# New Xcode 14.1 warnings that I can no longer use @Environment in App, Scene, and ObservableObjects anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In Xcode 14.1, I am getting many new run-time warnings that were not there before:

`Accessing Environment<Optional<MyType>>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update.`

Below is an example that shows warnings in Xcode 14.1 but not 14.0:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ContentModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Counter")
                .badge(model.counter)
            Stepper("Action", value: $model.counter)
            Text("Dependencies")
                .badge(model.test)
        }
    }
}

class ContentModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0

    @Environment(\.dependencies) var dependencies
    lazy var test = dependencies.formatted() // <== "Accessing Environment<Date>'s value outside of being installed on a View. This will always read the default value and will not update."
}


extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dependencies: Date { .now }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am using `@Environment` in my `App`, `Scene`, and `ObservableObjects`. Now that this is explicitly discouraged, is there another way to do this? I was trying to piggyback off `EnvironmentValues` for my DI, but not being able to use it outside of views is limiting and hoping for a native alternative.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that environment values are « A collection of environment values propagated through a view hierarchy.». You will have to create your own shared struct or class to do the same approach using your own property wrapper. Apple may have changed the underlying code to use some specifity of a view protocol.

Comment: Environment doesn’t work in a class only a SwiftUI View, people have used it but it isn’t stable, it depends on the Jody for updates , you have to change your approach like creating your own wrapper that doesn’t use DynamicProperty